# Get result from Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have multiple tasks returning the same object type that I want to call using  `Task.WhenAll(new[]{t1,t2,t3});`  and read the results.

When I try using

```
Task<List<string>> all = await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { t, t2 }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I get a compiler error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to
>   `'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>`

both tasks are calling method similar the this.

```
private Task<List<string>> GetFiles(string path)
{
    files = new List<string>();
    return  Task.Run(() =>
    {
       //remove for brevity 
        return files;
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what part of MSDN sample for [WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not clear? Would make question easier to answer.

Comment: Actually none of the article is not clear. What is not clear is where this void is coming from.

Comment: I see - as Mike Hixson pointed out you have list of `Task` (task that does not return value) instead of `Task<String>` - hence await results in `void`. Normally you just not specify type by using shortcut array syntax to avoid such issues - `ask.WhenAll(new[] { t, t2 })...`. or use properly typed list/array of tasks as shown in MSDN sample - `var tasks = new List<Task<long>>();`.

Comment: ^ This is the real answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like you are using the overload of `WaitAll()` that doesn't return a value. If you make the following changes, it should work.

```
List<string>[] all = await Task.WhenAll(new Task<List<string>>[] { t, t2 })
                               .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Or just `List<string>[] all = await Task.WhenAll(t, t2).ConfigureAwait(false);`

Answer (score 4):

The return type of WhenAll is a task whose result type is an array of the individual tasks' result type, in your case `Task<List<string>[]>`

When used in an await expression, the task will be "unwrapped" into its result type, meaning that the type of your "all" variable should be `List<string>[]`