# Task.WhenAll With Different Types

Tags: c#, async-await

I am getting a compiler error for the following line of code:

```
IEnumerable<IPurchasedItem<IFruit>>[] result = await Task.WhenAll(
                repository1.LoadItems(id),
                repository2.LoadItems(id)
                );
```

> Error  CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to
>    `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IPurchasedItem<IFruit>>[]`

My repository methods look like:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<IPurchasedItem<Apple>>> LoadItems(int id) {}
public async Task<IEnumerable<IPurchasedItem<Orange>>> LoadItems(int id) {}
```

...where `Apple` and `Orange` descend from:

```
public interface IPurchasedItem<out T> : where T : IFruit {}
public class Fruit : IFruit {}
public class Apple : Fruit {}
public class Orange : Fruit {}
```

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554080/get-result-from-task-whenall), but it seems like I'm already doing what's suggested, i.e. asking for `IEnumerable[]` rather than `Task<IEnumerable>[]`.

What am I doing wrong - and if this isn't the right approach then what is the best way for me to await and combine the results of both `LoadItems()` methods?
I was originally planning on doing:

```
result[0].Concat(result[1])
```

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766808/why-doesnt-this-exception-get-thrown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Task<T>` is a class, and therefore invariant. So a `Task<string>` is not a `Task<object>` - and as a more complicated example, a `Task<IEnumerable<IPurchasedItem<Apple>>>` is not a `Task<IEnumerable<IPurchasedItem<Fruit>>>` which is what you want it to be.

You could write a method to convert from one to another, of course - something like:

```
public static Task<TTarget> Convert<TSource, TTarget>(Task<TSource> task)
    where TSource : TTarget
{
    return await task;
}
```

Then you could convert all your specific tasks to `Task<IEnumerable<IPurchasedItem<Fruit>>>` tasks instead, and *then* `Task.WhenAll` will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I updated my question slightly to ask what the correct approach is, since this seems to be a dead end.

Comment: @Geoff: I've already told you want the correct approach is - transform your individual tasks into a common task type before calling `Task.WhenAll`. So you'd call `Convert<Apple, Fruit>(AppleFactory.LoadItems(...))` and `Convert<Orange, Fruit>(OrangeFactory.LoadItems(...))`, then call `Task.WhenAll` with the two results.

Comment: This is good - and thanks for pushing back and making me think a bit harder :)