# In .Net Core after Task.WhenAll, to get data is .Result is fine or need use await again to get data?

Tags: .net

```
await Task.WhenAll(existingServiceTask, cartServiceTask).ConfigureAwait(false);
var existingService = existingServiceTask.Result; //Is this ok? Any deawback of this?
var carInfo = await cartServiceTask;              //Or this is better?
```

> Try to understand after await WhenAll, if .Result is fine or has any drawbacks?

Comment: And some user here in SO adivses [not to await twice](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2019/08/prefer-valuetask-to-task-always-and.html)

Comment: I'd recommend simply to store the result of `await WaitAll`, though

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get result from Task.WhenAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554080/get-result-from-task-whenall)

Comment: @Pac0 that *is* referring to the difference between `Task<T>` and `ValueTask<T>`, but yes: it is a bad practice to get into

Comment: @MarcGravell Ah, thanks for clarifying this to me, author :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is as follows.

```
await Task.WhenAll(existingServiceTask, cartServiceTask).ConfigureAwait(false);
var existingService = await existingServiceTask;
var carInfo = await cartServiceTask;
```

Using `await` will protect you if you forget to put this task in `Task.WhenAll`